# Retain the resolution of the label after scaling in iphone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uilabel, scaling

I am having a label in a view.After scaling the view, the label looks little blurred,the resolution is lost.How to retain the resolution after scaling.

Here is my code for scaling

```
secondView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
secondView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2 ,2);
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:secondView];
```

Comment: What's your secondView.contentMode property value?

Comment: I didnt set that property at all..

Comment: I did guess you didn't, but I did ask what is this property value, never mind. Try to set it to *Redraw to force redrawing or redraw the view by yourself. Views are cached (kind of bitmaps) and these bitmaps are scaled up/down upon changes of some properties, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the ContentScaleFactor property of the label to retain the resolution of the label after scaling .

```
[label setContentScaleFactor:2];
```

Comment: This does not seem to work in my sample project. Can you provide an example application? My code: http://pastebin.com/9PFUTM4Y

Answer (score -2):

Create a label of big size itself, scale down using transformations when you add it to the view.
So at the run time when the view will scaleup the label's resolution will not be lost.

This is one of the approach.

Thanks