# Scaling UITextView using contentScaleFactor property

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uitextview, scaling

I am trying to create a higher resolution image of a `UIView`, specifically `UITextView`.

This question and answer is exactly what I am trying to figure out:

- [Retain the resolution of the label after scaling in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403118/retain-the-resolution-of-the-label-after-scaling-in-iphone/)

But, when I do the same, my text is *still* blurry:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.f, 2.f);
[myText setContentScaleFactor:2.f]; // myText is a subview of self.view object
```

I have also tried the same in the Apple sample project "UICatalog" to `UILabel` and it is also blurry.

I can't understand why it would work for Warrior from the other question and not for me. I would have asked there — but I can't seem to leave a comment or a question there.

Comment: did you find out why it did not work for you?

Answer (score 8):

Setting the `contentScaleFactor` and `contentsScale` is in fact the key, as @dbotha pointed out, however you have to walk the view and layer hierarchies separately in order to reach every internal `CATiledLayer` that actually does the text rendering. Adding the screen scale might also make sense.

So the correct implementation would be something like this:

```objc
- (void)updateForZoomScale:(CGFloat)zoomScale {
    CGFloat screenAndZoomScale = zoomScale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    // Walk the layer and view hierarchies separately. We need to reach all tiled layers.
    [self applyScale:(zoomScale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) toView:self.textView];
    [self applyScale:(zoomScale * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale) toLayer:self.textView.layer];
}

- (void)applyScale:(CGFloat)scale toView:(UIView *)view {
    view.contentScaleFactor = scale;
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [self applyScale:scale toView:subview];
    }
}

- (void)applyScale:(CGFloat)scale toLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    layer.contentsScale = scale;
    for (CALayer *sublayer in layer.sublayers) {
        [self applyScale:scale toLayer:sublayer];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this not the selected answer?  There are dozens of questions with the same exact issue and this is absolutely the ONLY solution that works for me.

Comment: Hey, Why did you said 'CATiledLayer' when referring UITextView? It's not the regular superclass layer. Did you changed it?

Answer (score 2):

UITextView has `textInputView` property, which "both draws the text and provides a coordinate system" (https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput/1614564-textinputview)

So i'm using the following code to scale UITextView - without any font changes, without using any "CALayer" property and keeping high quality:

```
float screenScaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
float scale = 5.0;
textView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale);
textView.textInputView.contentScaleFactor = screenScaleFactor * scale;
```

Comment the last line if you need low quality (but better performance) scaling.

Transform uses view.center as scaling center point, so adding a 'translate transform' is needed to scale around view corner.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to apply the contentScaleFactor to all subviews of the UITextView. I've just tested the following with a UITextView and found it to work:

```
- (void)applyScale:(CGFloat)scale toView:(UIView *)view {
    view.contentScaleFactor = scale;
    view.layer.contentsScale = scale;
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        [self applyScale:scale toView:subview];
    }
}
```