# Text blurs of UILabel on applying Pinch Gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel, uipinchgesturerecognizer

[image]
I am resizing UILabel with UIPinchGestureRecognizer but also text with label blurs with pinching.
Please help. I am using following code for pinching label.

```
-(void)handlePinchGesture:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGesture
{
    float scale = pinchGesture.scale;
    UIView *view = (UIView *)pinchGesture.view;
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
    {
         if (([pinchGesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [pinchGesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged))
         {           
                   [pinchGesture view].transform = CGAffineTransformScale([lbl transform],scale, scale);
                   [pinchGesture setScale:1];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please help with what? Could you show us what is going wrong please.

Answer (score 1):

See 
[iOS: Scaling UITextView with pinching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669457/ios-scaling-uitextview-with-pinching)

```
- (void)scaleTextView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestRecognizer{
     CGFloat scale = pinchGestRecognizer.scale;

    createTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:createTextView.font.fontName size:createTextView.font.pointSize*scale];

    [self textViewDidChange:createTextView];       
}
```

Hope that helps! Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

**Edited :**

Try this:

```
-(void)pinchLabel:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
CGFloat pinchScale = recognizer.scale;
_lblDouble.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0*pinchScale];
```

}

Comment: No, its not working. Can we set font size by UILabel's frame ??

Comment: What you mean by setting the font size by UILabel's frame? Can you give an example?