# Strange behaviour when typing into a text field after scaling it down using pinch gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have set up a subclass of `UITextView` which expands and shrinks to fit the text as the user types, called FlexibleText. I also have a Pinch Gesture Recognizer on this text view allowing users to scale it up and down.

However, when I pinch to scale the text view down, then try to edit it again, after typing any character the `UITextContainerView` scales down inside the text view, cutting off some of the text.

I'd be really grateful for any help in figuring this out!
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

class FlexibleText: UITextView {
    var horizontalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var verticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
}

var currentTextView = FlexibleText()

var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
var screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //add close keyboard recognizer
    let closeKeyboardRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(closeKeyboardRecognizer)

    let text1 = FlexibleText()
    text1.text = "your text"
    text1.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
    text1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    text1.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 250, height: 100)
    text1.isScrollEnabled = false
    text1.delegate = self
    text1.textAlignment = .center
    view.addSubview(text1)

    // layout
    text1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    text1.horizontalConstraint = text1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
    text1.horizontalConstraint?.isActive = true

    text1.verticalConstraint = text1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
    text1.verticalConstraint?.isActive = true

    text1.widthConstraint = text1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250)
    text1.widthConstraint?.isActive = true
    text1.heightConstraint = text1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    text1.heightConstraint?.isActive = true

    adjustTextViewHeight(text1)
    currentTextView = text1

    //add pinch gesture
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(pinchRecognized))
    pinchGesture.delegate = self
    text1.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)

}


// flexible functions
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    adjustTextViewHeight(textView)
}

func adjustTextViewHeight(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    if let currentView = textView as? FlexibleText {

        if newSize.width <= screenWidth {
            currentView.widthConstraint?.constant = newSize.width
        } else if newSize.width > screenWidth {
            currentView.widthConstraint?.constant = screenWidth
        }

        currentView.heightConstraint?.constant = newSize.height
    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}



@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}


//pinch gesture
@objc func pinchRecognized(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    if let view = recognizer.view as? FlexibleText {

        if recognizer.state == .changed {

            view.transform = view.transform.scaledBy(x: recognizer.scale, y: recognizer.scale)

        } else if recognizer.state == .ended {
            view.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40 * recognizer.scale)
        }

        adjustTextViewHeight(view)
        recognizer.scale = 1.0

    }

}



}
```

Here is an image of before scaling down:

[image: example]

and after:

[image: example]

And a screenshot of the view hierarchy:

[image: example]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this with the help of this answer: [iOS: Scaling UITextView with pinching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669457/ios-scaling-uitextview-with-pinching)

It involves only changing the font size on scale, and then adjusting the text view size to that. Here is my working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

class FlexibleText: UITextView {
    var horizontalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var verticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
}

var currentTextView = FlexibleText()

var screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
var screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //add close keyboard recognizer
    let closeKeyboardRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(closeKeyboardRecognizer)

    let text1 = FlexibleText()
    text1.text = "your text"
    text1.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
    text1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    text1.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 250, height: 100)
    text1.isScrollEnabled = false
    text1.delegate = self
    text1.textAlignment = .center
    view.addSubview(text1)


    // layout
    text1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    text1.horizontalConstraint = text1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
    text1.horizontalConstraint?.isActive = true

    text1.verticalConstraint = text1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100)
    text1.verticalConstraint?.isActive = true

    text1.widthConstraint = text1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250)
    text1.widthConstraint?.isActive = true
    text1.heightConstraint = text1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    text1.heightConstraint?.isActive = true


    adjustTextViewSize(text1)
    currentTextView = text1

    //add pinch gesture
    let pinchGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(pinchRecognized))
    pinchGesture.delegate = self
    text1.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGesture)



}


// flexible functions
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    adjustTextViewSize(textView)
}



func adjustTextViewSize(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    textView.frame = CGRect(x: (textView.frame.minX), y: (textView.frame.minY), width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    if let currentView = textView as? FlexibleText {

        if newSize.width <= screenWidth {
            currentView.widthConstraint?.constant = newSize.width
        } else if newSize.width > screenWidth {
            currentView.widthConstraint?.constant = screenWidth
        }

        currentView.heightConstraint?.constant = newSize.height

    }

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}



@objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}


//pinch gesture
@objc func pinchRecognized(recognizer: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {

    let scale:CGFloat = recognizer.scale

    guard let textView = recognizer.view as? FlexibleText else { return }

    textView.font = UIFont(name: textView.font!.fontName, size: textView.font!.pointSize*scale)

    adjustTextViewSize(textView)

    recognizer.scale = 1.0

}



}
```

Answer (score -1):

add this code

`currentTextView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollView.ContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior.never' into your method 'viewDidLoad()`

Comment: i added that in, but still getting the issue - was it working for you? thanks

Comment: after scale down. you should change textView's width and height as well. then the problem will be solved.