# How to zoom TextField when focused?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to zoom in the text field when it is focused. I know how to move up or down the text field if keyboard appears or disappears. However, having no idea how to zoom in or zoom out the text field.

Comment: like browser do for iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

After setting the delegate for UITextField.Try this, Hope it will help to you.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    textField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5);
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        textField.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Zoom In using `contentScaleFactor` . 
You can refere to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927223/scaling-uitextview-using-contentscalefactor-property) for further explaination